# A strange series of words

Tags: riddle, pattern

An entry into the [20th fortnightly topic challenge](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5631/fortnightly-topic-challenge-20-pattern?cb=1)

---

What are these lists of words trying to point to?

> Boot percentage jee, tee afternoon dee few
> Mouth ohm thenceforth mother offends see Earth
> Tee taste lack ɘ pre eff gist
> Mix right he is a digit desists
>
> Book dollar key, why morning see couple
> Nose I'm thence father offend bee Venus
> Why smell lake ɚ post dee fist
> Mixes left she is the number resists
>
> Loot pound lee, you pm bee one
> Ear em then uncle off flat-bee Mercury
> You sight lick ɵ before es dist
> Mixing down you are a letter desist

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The answer is**

> **SISTER**

Because, as others have pointed out:

> The puzzle hints at a fourth stanza made up of words formed by following the pattern for each parallel set of words in the first three.

> The missing stanza, borrowing heavily from Alconja but with some key corrections, is:
>
>  *Look at me I am a nun*
>  *I am the aunt of a son*
>  *I sound like **ə** after a cyst*
>  *Mixed up I am the word resist*

The final solution:

> A nun is a sister.
>  If you have a son, your sister is his aunt.   — Thanks @Gareth!
>  Phonetically, "cyst" + **ə** (actually **ə r**) would sound like *sister*.
>  And **sister** is an anagram of **resist**

---

**The gory details**

First line:

> $\small\begin{array}{lll} \phantom{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\\text{- Boot,Book,Loot → Look}&&\text{first letter doubles, b/b/l/l; last letter alternates t/k/t/k}\\ \text{- percentage,dollar,pound → at}&&\text{names of top row symbols on QWERTY,}\\ &&\ \ \ \ \text{in order backward from shift-5 to shift-2}\\ \text{- jee,kee,lee → mee⇒me}&&\text{{j/k/l/m letter run}+“ee”, then made into a word}\\ \text{- afternoon,morning,pm → am}&&\text{afternoon:morning :: pm:am}\\ \text{- dee,see,bee → a}&&\text{d/c/b/a letter run}\\ \text{- few,couple,one → none⇒nun}&&\text{3/2/1/0 sequence as words, then homophoned}\end{array}$

Second line:

> $\small\begin{array}{lll} \phantom{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\\text{- Mouth,Nose,Ear → Eye⇒I}&&\text{parts of the face, then homophoned}\\ \text{- ohm,I'm,em → am}&&\text{{o/i/e/a (reverse) vowel sequence}+“m”}\\ \text{- thenceforth,thence,then → the}&&\text{incremental truncations that still form words}\\ \text{- mother,father,uncle → aunt}&&\text{male and female words for types of relatives}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{(better might be  father:mother :: uncle:aunt)}\\ \text{- offends,offend,off → of}&&\text{incremental truncations that still form words}\\ \text{- see,bee,flat-bee → a}&&\text{sequence of musical half-tones, C, B, B♭, A}\\ \text{- Earth,Venus,Mercury → Sun⇒son}&&\text{Solar System from Earth inward, then homophoned}\end{array}$

Third line:

> $\small\begin{array}{lll} \phantom{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\\text{- Tee,Why,You → I}&&\text{(homophones for) 2nd row QWERTY letters t/y/u/i}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{(previously was “Why,You,Oh”, an error)}\\ \text{- taste,smell,sight → sound}&&\text{senses.  (It would have been more symmetric if the senses}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{were aligned with the parts of the face from line 2,}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{but it certainly isn't a flaw that they're not)}\\ \text{- lack,lake,lick → like}&&\text{“l”+{alternating short vowel/long vowel sounds, ă/ā/ĭ/ī}}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{+{alternating ck/ke/ck/ke}}\\ \text{- ɘ,ɚ,ɵ → ə}&&\text{‘e’-like IPA (pronunciation) symbols}\\ \text{- pre,post,before → after}&&\text{pre:post :: before:after}\\ \text{- eff,dee,es → a}&&\text{home row QWERTY letters in backward order f/d/s/a}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{(note: “es” s/b “ess”? ...was originally “see”, an error)}\\ \text{- gist,fist,dist → sist⇒cyst}&&\text{{home row QWERTY letters in backward order g/f/d/s}}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{+“ist”, then made into a word}\end{array}$

Fourth line:

> $\small\begin{array}{lll} \phantom{XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX}\\\text{- Mix,Mixes,Mixing → Mixed}&&\text{tenses of “to mix”}\\ \text{- right,left,down → up}&&\text{directional words; right:left :: down:up}\\ \text{- he,she,you → I}&&\text{singular pronouns, progressing from}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{3rd person to 2nd person to 1st person}\\ \text{- is,is,are → am}&&\text{conjugation of “to be” for the preceding pronoun}\\ \text{- a,the,a → the}&&\text{articles, alternating between a/the/a/the}\\ \text{- digit,number,letter → word}&&\text{digit:number :: letter:word}\\ \text{- desists,resists,desist → resist}&&\text{first letter alternates d/r/d/r;}\\&&\ \ \ \ \text{first two are inflected, second two are not s/s/ / }\end{array}$

Comment: Two things to go: daughter is not right, and neither is exist. The 'you' in the third line is also not correct but is inconsequential.

Comment: For sist, I used the word cyst (or cist in some alternative spellings).

Comment: not getting the relations relations :)   I think I'm missing something for that one word.

Comment: If you have a son, your sister is his aunt.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Thanks!  Figured it'd be something stupidly simple that I miss. hehe

Comment: This is my first attempt at writing a riddle, is it good? Also, would you mind adding explanations for other users who might see the puzzle?

Comment: The resulting riddle was pretty simple but still fun; the puzzle to arrive at the riddle was, of course, the meat of the post here, and was quite enjoyable to get through.  I've now added detailed explanations for each parallel set of words to provide their patterns.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer (more of reasoning aloud in an attempt to help other solvers):

> Each word from each verse, when taken with its counterparts from the other verses, form a sort of sequence. I'm assuming that putting together all the logical 'next steps' in each sequence will hint to the answer.

For instance:

> Boot -> Book -> Loot -> Look?

And:

> percentage -> dollar -> pound -> at (symbols on a keyboard, I didn't get it because my keyboard's symbol for 3 is #)
>  jee -> key -> lee -> mee? (j, k, l, m)
>  tee -> why -> you -> i (t, y, u, i on a keyboard)
>  afternoon -> morning -> pm -> am?
>  dee -> see -> bee -> a (d, c, b, a)
>  few -> couple -> one -> zero

As @Alconja pointed out, the first line of the "clue" should then read:

> Look at me I am a zero.

Answer (score 3):

**Partial answer....**

> Each word in each list transforms from one group to the next, hinting at a fourth list, which is actually a riddle of sorts.

For example:

> First words in each group are "Boot" => "Book" => "Loot" => ?? hinting at "Look" (first letters follow the pattern B, B, L, L and last letters follow T, K, T, K)

Using similar logic, we get something like:

> Look at me. I am a zero(?)
>  I am the ??? of a son.
>  You ??? (probably 'sound') like ??? after ??? sist ('assist' based on the sequences)-
>  mixed up I am a character (guessing 'word') resist

Comment: I had exactly the same idea but you got quite a bit further than I did with the same logic. Darn.

Comment: @Xenocacia - great minds and all that... :)